# Javascript: repeat function

Tags: javascript

I have a function with `if` inside. In case `if` returns `false` I need repeat function again

```
this.reloadComment = function () {
        var previous_comment = self.Comment();
        $.getJSON(Routes.my_service_search_path(self.ID), {}, function (data) {
            if (data.Comment.ID != previous_comment.ID) {
                self.Comment(data.Comment);
            } else {
                // repeat
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: What's the problem? Just call the function again.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi the problem is don't know how do it inside function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `self` within the function is what `this` is outside it, then simply:

```
} else {
    // repeat
    self.reloadComment();
}
```

If not, use a named function; then since you have that nice name you can use, call it when you need to repeat it:

```
function reloadComment() {
    var previous_comment = self.Comment();
    $.getJSON(Routes.my_service_search_path(self.ID), {}, function (data) {
        if (data.Comment.ID != previous_comment.ID) {
            self.Comment(data.Comment);
        } else {
            // repeat
            reloadComment();
        }
    });
}
this.reloadComment = reloadComment;
```

If you don't need to support IE8, you can do that with a single *named* function expression:

```
this.reloadComment = function reloadComment() {
    var previous_comment = self.Comment();
    $.getJSON(Routes.my_service_search_path(self.ID), {}, function (data) {
        if (data.Comment.ID != previous_comment.ID) {
            self.Comment(data.Comment);
        } else {
            // repeat
            reloadComment();
        }
    });
};
```

...but on IE8 (and earlier) [you'd end up with two copies of that function, not one](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/double-take.html); if you do that a lot, it ends up being wasteful. (It wouldn't make any other difference *in this particular case*, though; it'd still work. There are other situations where it *would* make a difference, so I stay away from NFEs entirely in code that needs to deal with IE8.)

Answer (score 1):

**Try This**

```
this.reloadComment = function () {
    var me = this;
    var previous_comment = self.Comment();
    $.getJSON(Routes.my_service_search_path(self.ID), {}, function (data) {
        if (data.Comment.ID != previous_comment.ID) {
            self.Comment(data.Comment);
        } else {
           me.reloadComment();
        }
    });
};
```